# Finding ring road of subway scheme

Tags: c++, algorithm

i have a problem, i have been thinking about this for a while.

example :

```
1-2
3-4
6-4
2-3
1-3
3-5
```

note : "a-b" mean 'a' connected to 'b' and 'b' connected to 'a'

how can i find a longest ring-road; 
 
it's 1-2-3 cause 1-2, 1-3, 2-3 from example.

i'm thinking bout using brute-force but that doesnt seems to work cause it can't calculate up to 3000 combination

i'm thinking about possible faster algorithm but doesnt seem to get a good idea

Comment: What is your brute force method?

Comment: LOL ! The contest is still going on. Wait for the editorials if you are not able to solve it now.

Comment: 3000 combinations shouldn't be a problem.  I suspect that if you only have 6 vertices, brute force would be the way to go.

Comment: @logic_max i'm not gonna solve it now. i'm just wanting to learn. if u can, u can just answer it after the contest over

Comment: @James Kanze it could go up to 3000 vertices

Comment: @zeulb That's something else than 3000 combinations.  That would exclude brute force. (I don't know any general algorithm, but for starters, you could drop any entries where one of the end points only appeared once.  Recursively.  That would simplify things a little.)

Comment: It is the traveling salesman problem - but dressed up!

Answer (score 1):

The problem says that there is only one ringroad. So, any graph that you look would be of the form as shown. The problem also says that you can get from one vertex to any other one, that is, graph is connected.

```
        _ _ _ _
  _ _ _/        \
       |         |_ _ _
        \_ _ _ _/
```

So, if you apply `DFS` from any vertex, then you will be in the ringroad. You can take a hash, and keep marking the vetices as you visit them. When you visit the same vertex again, you are in the ringroad.

**EDIT:** As @Saeed points out, distance of vertices from railroad can be found out easily in O(n). You can go round the ringroad, move to the edge updating the distances, and then continue on the ringroad.

I would advise you to wait for the tutorials.

Comment: There is no need to start a BFS from any vertext not in ring road, first can remove connection from ringroad  vertices , then start from any vertex in ring road and find related vertices and their distances, which is O(n). (because remaining graph is jungle).

Comment: Do you have a ref for "jungle" term?  Note, the graph remaining after deleting ringroad vertices is a [forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29).  Any connected undirected graph with n edges and n vertices is the union of a ring and a forest.

Comment: @jwpat7 I say Jungle to what you say Forest, and this is because it's close to our Persian language and I guess everyone can guess what I'm talking about, and I'm the reference you want :)

Answer (score 0):

From a theoretical point of view, it will be difficult to have an effective algorithm.

If you have an algorithm that finds the longest loop without going twice over the same edge, you're able to solve the Halmitonian path problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path

So you have un NP-Complete algorithm. So there is rather little chance to have a polynomial algorithm.

Is really bruteforce a problem with 3000 stations ? I would do a bfs on every node and everytime you hit the departure node, I'd store it as the longest ring.

Comment: Not really, since he doesn't have the constraint that he has to visit every node.

Comment: The problem is very restricted. There is only one loop.